# SignalR slow initiating connection (and retrieving data)

Tags: signalr, signalr.client

I have started experiencing a performance issue, particularly after upgrading to version 2.2.0.

With more complicated pages, which use sever different hubs, it can take up to 30 seconds to initiate a connection:

```
[16:20:35 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: serverSentEvents transport connected. Initiating start request.
[16:21:05 GMT+0100 (GMT Daylight Time)] SignalR: The start request succeeded. Transitioning to the connected state.
```

To demonstrate the issue, I have created a test page, which only uses one hub. I call a server method on the hub and only retrieve one int value, without doing any database calls or any complicated calculations.

```
define(["knockout", "jquery", "signalr"],
    function (ko, $) {
        function SignalRTestViewModel() {
            var self = this;
            var connection = $.connection.dashboardHub;

            self.init = function () {
                connection.server.signalRTest();
            };

            self.test = ko.observable();

            connection.client.populateSignalRTest = function (test) {
                self.test(test);
            };
        }

        return SignalRTestViewModel;
    })
```

It still takes 2-3 seconds to initiate the connection and another 2 seconds to retrieve just that one int value.

[image]

The issue is the same for different transport methods (serverSentEvents, longPolling) and exists in all browsers.

I'm not too sure how to narrow down the issue and what can be causing those delays. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of debugging I found out that one of the dependencies, which was being resolved in quite a few of my services, was verifying Lucene search index every time it was resolved (which was completely unnecessary).

Commented it out and everything seems OK.